# How to calculate price By retrieving one value from firebase database and other through elegantNumberButton

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i want to calculate price of the car slot selected by the user. The price of the slot per hour is saved in firebase database and user can select duration(Hours) through elegant button number. I have created a model class for slot to retrieve Price of the selected slot as follows:

```
public class Slots {

private String Price;


 // empty constructor...
//getter and setter methods...
```

In Main Activity, I have the following code:

```
Selectbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            int fair=0;
            fair+=(Integer.parseInt(currentSlot.getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(duration.getNumber()));
            totalprice.setText(fair);

        }
    });
```

currentSlot is the object of Slot model class and duration is the elegant number button. I have converted them into Integers and then multiplied price per hour with the duration(number of hours). When i click the button it says my app has stopped working. Please help me with the answer
[image: Json node]

Answer (score 0):

after seeing your code the problem is that you are getting `NumberFormatException` in converting string to integer you have String with `non-digit characters`

I would suggest replacing all `non-digit characters` from String first converting to `int`

```
String price= "10SR/hr";
String priceInDigits= price.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
```

add `Try/Catch` in your code and Read Exception using debugging .!

```
Selectbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                try {
                    int fair = 0;
                    fair += (Integer.parseInt(currentSlot.getPrice())) * (Integer.parseInt(duration.getNumber()));
                    totalprice.setText(fair);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.getMessage();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Exception : " + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ex.getStackTrace();
                }

            }
});
```